# What is ACS on a magneto switch?

Tags: piston-engine, electrical-system

I was looking at a magneto switch and the text ACS below attracted my attention. What is its meaning and function?

[image]

Comment: Where is this photo from?

Comment: Related question: why are so many altimeters calibrated for winter conditions? :)

Comment: What does the label on the top read?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's the brand name. ACS is a company that makes aircraft parts, among them [ignition switches](https://acsproducts.co/our-products/acs-ignition-switches/a-510-5-ignition-switch/).